# dict to str как преобразовать с возможностью изменения строки

Tags: python, json, dict, decode

Как преобразовать словарь в строку, заменив при этом запятую на точку с запятой.
Пример: {key: value, key: value} на входе, на выходе нужно 'key: value; key: value'

json.dumps(dict) и json(loads) пробовала, но json.loads не работает когда я делаю replace (',',';') по строке из json.dumps(dict). json.dumps(dict) - вывод не в той кодировке, преобразовать в python формат не смогла
Как преобразовать так, чтобы я могла внести изменения в эту строку, сохранив при этом кодировку

Comment: вы еще упоминаете кодировку. Что вы подразумеваете под "не в той кодировке"? Вы могли помочь отвечающим если бы в сам вопрос добавили реальные данные, с которыми работаете, нажав [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1337370/edit) под самим вопросом

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
s = "; ".join(f"{k}:{v}" for k, v in d.items())
# Результат '1:2; 3:4'
```

Comment: Как вариант - `s = '; '.join(map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}:{x[1]}', d.items()))`

Answer (score 1):

JSON и словарь Python - это не одно и то же, поэтому вам методы json тут и не нужны. Вот, к примеру, самый простой вариант решения вашей задачи:

```
my_dict = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
my_str = str(my_dict) # создаем строку, содержащую наш словарь
formated_str = my_str.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace(",", ";") 
# убираем фигурные скобки и заменяем запятую на точку с запятой
print(formated_str)
```

либо таким способом:

```
my_dict = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
my_str = "" #создаем пустую строку
for key, value in my_dict.items(): # в цикле перебираем пары ключ: значение
    my_str = my_str + key + ": " + value + "; " # добавляем к строке запись нужного формата
print (my_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

все просто

```
my_dict = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}

str(my_dict).replace(",", ";")[1:-1] 

# вывод
'key1': 'value1'; 'key2': 'value2'
```

**UPD** (согласно комментарию от @GrAnd)
Метод описанный выше не является универсальным и скорей всего не пройдет проверку и тестирование. Отсюда и вытекают некие требования к задающему вопрос:

1. Входные данные
2. Выходные данные

Те входные и выходные данные, что указаны не являются корректными (key - уникальное значение) и берутся как пример.

Какая в итоге логика нужна? поразмышляем.

Вопрос: преобразовать словарь в строку с возможностью изменения строки.
Строка - это изменяемый тип данных, и изменения можно внести всегда. Словарь в строку, не проблема. Указаний на то, что будет содержать словарь нет, примеров реальных входных данных нет. Данный метод "посыпется", как только появится запятая в данных. Или не посыпется? Нужно, ли, все запятые заменить на точку с запятой.

Следующее. Если, же, нужно заменить запятые между парами ключ-значение, то естественно, необходимо выбрать метод, который так или иначе перебирает словарь.

Обычный for словаря, где `d.items()` - список кортежей:

```py
string = ""
for key, value in d.items(): 
  string += f"{key}:{value};"
```

Можно и дальше пойти и использовать `collections`, только зачем. Вот и возникает вопрос о входных и выходных данных.

Можно и дальше смотреть на тему типов данных. ТС использует `json`. Вопрос: почему? Данные приходят в этом виде? Тогда, до преобразования в словарь это последовательность символов. Может на этом этапе обрабатывать?

и так далее

Comment: И не дай бог запятая встретится где-нибудь в именах ключей или в их значениях... ;)